# Change href with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2003

I am trying to add a click event to a link in SharePoint. 
The current href set by SharePoint is `href="javascript:ClickOnce()"`. 
If I add the following code:

```
var saveNclose = document.getElementById("diidIOSaveItem");
saveNclose.href = "javascript:JSEPreSaveAction()";
alert(saveNclose.href);
```

The alert outputs the href I am trying to get, which is `javascript:PreSaveAction()` but when I look at it in the page it is still `ClickOnce()`.

Why is the alert telling me the href is one thing and the source code and behavior says is another? Is there something causing SharePoints script to take priority over mine?

Comment: How are you viewing the source code?

Comment: In Internet Explorer by pressing F12

Comment: Strange, I'm able to do almost exactly what you're doing successfully here: http://jsfiddle.net/xZ6nC/. Could there be a typo: `diidIOSaveItem` should be `didIOSaveItem`? Although if that was the case and `diidIOSaveItem` didn't exist, you'd just get a JS error telling you that `null` has no property `href`...

Comment: One thing I just thought of, SharePoint is running its own script to add ClickOnce() to the link I believe. I think mine is running, triggering the alert and then SharePoint is changing it back to ClickOnce(). Looking into how I can make sure mine runs last now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding a timer to add PreSaveAction() to the button 10 seconds after the page had finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("diidIOSaveItem").setAttribute("href", "javascript:JSEPreSaveAction()");

alert( document.getElementById("diidIOSaveItem").getAttribute("href") );
```

Comment: Just tested this and got the same result. It alerts JSEPreSaveAction() but the href remains ClickOnce()